# Swift3 How to set properties created in an extension

Tags: uiviewcontroller, swift3, swift-protocols

I have a function in my UIViewControllers to setup a UINavigationBar which is repeated in many functions. I want to create the navigation bar in an extension but I want to set the title text and a cart label in each function. How can I do this? I think the answer is to use protocols but I'm not sure how.

Here is my extension

```
extension UIViewController {

func shoppingBagButtonTouched(button: UIButton) {
    -----        
}

func closeView() {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func setupNavigationHeader(showCart: Bool? = true) {

    let navigationBar: UINavigationBar = {
        let navBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, Constants.HEADER_HEIGHT))
        return navBar
    }()

    let navigationItem = UINavigationItem()

    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false

    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .red

    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .white

    let titleLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.backgroundColor = .clear
        label.layer.masksToBounds = true
        label.minimumScaleFactor = 10/UIFont.labelFontSize
        label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        label.numberOfLines = 1
        label.text = "not set"
        label.textColor = .white
        return label
    }()

    let fixedSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .fixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)

    let menuBtn = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "closeNav"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.closeView))

    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [fixedSpace, menuBtn]

    navigationBar.items = [navigationItem]

    if let showCart = showCart {

        let cartCountLabel: UILabel = {
            let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: -0, width: 20, height: 20))
            label.textAlignment = .center
            label.layer.cornerRadius = label.bounds.size.height / 2
            label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            label.backgroundColor = .clear
            label.layer.masksToBounds = true
            label.textColor = .white
            label.minimumScaleFactor = 10/UIFont.labelFontSize
            label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
            return label
        }()

        let shoppingBagButton: UIButton = {
            let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 22, height: 22))
            button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "shopping_bag"), for: .normal)
            return button
        }()

        let rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: shoppingBagButton)

        navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([rightBarButtonItem], animated: true)

        shoppingBagButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(shoppingBagButtonTouched(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        shoppingBagButton.addSubview(cartCountLabel)
        cartCountLabel.anchorCenterXToSuperview()
        cartCountLabel.anchorCenterYToSuperview(constant: 2)
    }

    navigationBar.addSubview(titleLabel)

    view.addSubview(navigationBar)

    titleLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    titleLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navigationBar.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    titleLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20.0).isActive = true
    titleLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 90).isActive = true
}
}
```

In each controller I have code like this to set the title label and cart label but it doesn't work when I create the nav bar in an extension.

```
var titleLabelText: String = "title not set"

var cartCount: String? {
    didSet {
        cartCountLabel.text = cartCount
    }
}

func getCartCount() {
    ServerUtility.getCartCountApi { (cartCount) in
        if let count = cartCount as Int? {
            if count > 0 {
                self.cartCount = "\(count)"
            }
        } else {
            self.cartCount = "0"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you call `setupNavigationHeader`? Also, I don't see where you define `cartCountLabel` as a value accessible from your view controller(s). It appears to be just a local variable in your extension ...

Comment: I call `setupNavigationHeader()` from `viewDidLoad()`. `cartCountLabel` is just a local variable in my extension.. That's the point, I want to keep all of this code DRY and in one place.

Comment: Then you are better off using a base class of `UIViewController` to base all your view controllers off of instead of trying to add an extension. With a base class, you can have properties (like `cartCountLabel`) that your subclasses can access. Is there a reason for not going with a base class?

Comment: No, I am a noobie and wondering what's the best way tp go about this. Thanks. Please write that up as an answer with some more detail.

Comment: Ah, sorry :) Can't always tell how much somebody knows and I try not to assume :p Will add code showing you the base class approach ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably best off creating a base class extending `UIViewController` something like this:

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {
        let cartCountLabel: UILabel = {
            let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: -0, width: 20, height: 20))
            label.textAlignment = .center
            label.layer.cornerRadius = label.bounds.size.height / 2
            label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            label.backgroundColor = .clear
            label.layer.masksToBounds = true
            label.textColor = .white
            label.minimumScaleFactor = 10/UIFont.labelFontSize
            label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
            return label
        }()

func shoppingBagButtonTouched(button: UIButton) {
    -----        
}

func closeView() {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func setupNavigationHeader(showCart: Bool? = true) {

    let navigationBar: UINavigationBar = {
        let navBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, Constants.HEADER_HEIGHT))
        return navBar
    }()

    let navigationItem = UINavigationItem()

    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false

    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .red

    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .white

    let titleLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.backgroundColor = .clear
        label.layer.masksToBounds = true
        label.minimumScaleFactor = 10/UIFont.labelFontSize
        label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        label.numberOfLines = 1
        label.text = "not set"
        label.textColor = .white
        return label
    }()

    let fixedSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .fixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)

    let menuBtn = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "closeNav"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.closeView))

    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [fixedSpace, menuBtn]

    navigationBar.items = [navigationItem]

    if let showCart = showCart {

        let shoppingBagButton: UIButton = {
            let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 22, height: 22))
            button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "shopping_bag"), for: .normal)
            return button
        }()

        let rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: shoppingBagButton)

        navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([rightBarButtonItem], animated: true)

        shoppingBagButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(shoppingBagButtonTouched(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        shoppingBagButton.addSubview(cartCountLabel)
        cartCountLabel.anchorCenterXToSuperview()
        cartCountLabel.anchorCenterYToSuperview(constant: 2)
    }

    navigationBar.addSubview(titleLabel)

    view.addSubview(navigationBar)

    titleLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    titleLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navigationBar.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    titleLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20.0).isActive = true
    titleLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 90).isActive = true
}
}
```

Then you can derive all your view controller instances from the base class like this:

```
class MyViewController:BaseViewController {
var titleLabelText: String = "title not set"

var cartCount: String? {
    didSet {
        cartCountLabel.text = cartCount
    }
}

func getCartCount() {
    ServerUtility.getCartCountApi { (cartCount) in
        if let count = cartCount as Int? {
            if count > 0 {
                self.cartCount = "\(count)"
            }
        } else {
            self.cartCount = "0"
        }
    }
}
}
```

I have not verified the above code by running it and so it might need a bit of tweaking :)